# Is it true that Cadwallon ap Cadfan married a half sister of Penda of Mercia?

Tags: england, monarchy, anglo-saxons

It was stated by Geoffrey of Monmouth in his pseudo historical [Historia Regnum Britannia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_Regum_Britanniae) that [Cadwallon ap Cadfan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadwallon_ap_Cadfan) married a half sister of [Penda of Mercia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penda_of_Mercia).

Did he get that from other sources? Is it true. If so it affects if the monarchs of Mercia have known descendants.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Fourth downvote tonight; you haven't read the wikpedia article on the former.

Comment: Not sure your point about descendants. There will be many people today who descend from Mercian royalty.